# eval("{}") vs eval ("x={}"), one returns undefined, while other {}

Tags: javascript

```
eval("x={}")

  -->  {}

eval("{}")

  -->  undefined
```

Why is that?

I want to return an object from an evaluated string.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: @Pointy, too many quotes to type. Besides it's node.js and a config is in the current directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`{}` is parsed as an empty block statement, not an object literal expression.

To force it to be parsed as an expression, wrap it in parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

`{}` is interpreted as a block containing no statements, which evaluates as `undefined`. `x={}` forces `{}` to be evaluated as an expression (the empty object) because you can't assign a block to anything. Then the assignment operator returns the value that was assigned.

A cleaner way to get the same effect would be to wrap the expression in parentheses. `eval("({})")` gives the right result for me.

Answer (score 0):

eval("{}+{}")
There's lots of errors in JavaScript.
Source: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat